# Getting error while run the selenium grid demo

Tags: selenium, selenium-grid, demo

I am learning to implement the selenium Grid.

When i tried to run the DEMO, it says the following error. Can any one help
me ?

D:\selenium-grid\selenium-grid-1.0.8>ant run-demo-in-sequence
Buildfile: build.xml

```
run-demo-in-sequence:
 [java] [Parser] Running:
 [java]   Selenium Grid Demo In Sequence
 [java]
 [java] Nov 7, 2011 4:30:19 PM
com.thoughtworks.selenium.grid.tools.ThreadSafeSeleniumSessionStorage
startSeleniumSession
 [java] INFO: Contacting Selenium RC at localhost:4444
 [java] Nov 7, 2011 4:30:19 PM
 com.thoughtworks.selenium.grid.tools.ThreadSafeSeleniumSessionStorage
closeSeleniumSession
 [java] INFO: Closing Selenese session:
 com.thoughtworks.selenium.DefaultSelenium@4d3c7378
 [java] Nov 7, 2011 4:30:19 PM
com.thoughtworks.selenium.grid.tools.ThreadSafeSeleniumSessionStorage
startSeleniumSession
 [java] INFO: Contacting Selenium RC at localhost:4444
 [java] Nov 7, 2011 4:30:19 PM
 com.thoughtworks.selenium.grid.tools.ThreadSafeSeleniumSessionStorage
 closeSeleniumSession
 [java] INFO: Closing Selenese session:
 com.thoughtworks.selenium.DefaultSelenium@788ab708
 [java] Nov 7, 2011 4:30:19 PM
 com.thoughtworks.selenium.grid.tools.ThreadSafeSeleniumSessionStorage
 startSeleniumSession
 [java] INFO: Contacting Selenium RC at localhost:4444
 [java] Nov 7, 2011 4:30:19 PM
 com.thoughtworks.selenium.grid.tools.ThreadSafeSeleniumSessionStorage
 closeSeleniumSession
 [java] INFO: Closing Selenese session:
 com.thoughtworks.selenium.DefaultSelenium@789934d4
 [java] Nov 7, 2011 4:30:19 PM
  com.thoughtworks.selenium.grid.tools.ThreadSafeSeleniumSessionStorage
  startSeleniumSession
 [java] INFO: Contacting Selenium RC at localhost:4444
 [java] Nov 7, 2011 4:30:19 PM
 com.thoughtworks.selenium.grid.tools.ThreadSafeSeleniumSessionStorage
  closeSeleniumSession
 [java] INFO: Closing Selenese session:
  com.thoughtworks.selenium.DefaultSelenium@3747c1db
  [java]
 *     [java] ===============================================*
 *     [java] Selenium Grid Demo In Sequence*
 *     [java] Total tests run: 4, Failures: 4, Skips: 0*
 *     [java] ===================================*============
  [java]

 *BUILD FAILED*
 D:\selenium-grid\selenium-grid-1.0.8\build.xml:116: Java returned: 1 
 Total time : 0 seconds
```

I didnt get any browser launch also..Please anyone help me.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Can you go to http://localhost:4444/ and confirm if grid is started?

Comment: ya its started and it shows Available Remote Controls

Host         Port  Environment
localhost 5555 *firefox

Comment: Hey now i solved the problem and i get the browser launch.But after the browser launch it stuck. i have waited for more than 10 min nothing happened..

Comment: This could be version compatibility issue dude. Check your selenium server version i know firefox version.

Comment: ya thanks i solved it..now i'm able to run the test, but after finished the test running it shows "INFO: Garbage collecting unavailable RCs and stale sessions..." and Build Failed.

Answer (score 0):

If you're just getting started, you should use Selenium Grid 2.  The demo you're using is for Selenium Grid 1, which is effectively a dead project.  All new effort is going into Grid 2, which is guaranteed to be backwards-compatible.

Please see http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/Grid2